# Como hacer para que salga mi Navbar en modo dispositivo

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hola a todos como puedo hacer para que mi navbar me aparezca en modo dispositivo movil, en modo web si me aparece.!

Espero y me puedan ayudar y no sea tan complicado

Asi es como se ve el navbar en la web, la he puesto fija para que al momento de ir bajando tengas el menu a la vista y no tengas que ir hasta el inicio para poder verlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en modo dispositivo se ve asi (no se ve)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo, no se si le falte algo (lo mas probable)

```css
.navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #0000;
            z-index: 9999;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
            /*letter-spacing: 4px;*/
            border-radius: 0;
            font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
        }

        .navbar li a,
        .navbar .navbar-brand {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover,
        .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: #fcc10f !important;
            /*background-color: #000 !important;*/
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            color: #fff !important;
        }
```

```html
<body id="inicio" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#menu1">MENU 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu2">MENU 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu3">MENU 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu4">MENU 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu5">MENU 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu6">MENU 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```